# Converting PDF to images preserving the vectorial quality

Tags: linux, pdf, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick to convert some PDF to files to PNG images, and I'm experiencing some quality problems because the generated image has very low quality.
I played with the density, resample, interpolate and filter flags of the convert command, but I did not manage in having an high quality image like I would make a screenshot from a PDF reader (which preserve the vectorial quality of the PDF file, of course).

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Have you tried the `-size` or `-resize` flag to specify a resolution?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Imagemagick will always rasterize your PDF, process the output raster image by applying whatever transformation you requested, then it will wrap the resulting raster image as PDF again and give you that as final result.

If you want the "vectorial features" of your PDF file to remain the same, then you should use ghostscript instead, which is what Imagemagick is using under the hoods anyways.